# Django-celery can't work in another environment but work in localhost

Tags: python, django, django-views, celery, django-celery

I try to learn and pratice celery with Django and it works only in a localhost environment. The problem that I have is when I build it on another environment it returns an error like this

```
web_1         |     app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
web_1         | TypeError: config_from_object() got an unexpected keyword argument 'namespace
```

I delete the `namespace='CELERY'` but it returns another error like `AttributeError: 'Overview' object has no attribute '__qualname__'`

I use `django-celery==3.3`

Here is my code:

celery.py
import os

```
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')

app = Celery('proj')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

app.autodiscover_tasks(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
app.autodiscover_tasks()
@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print(f'Request: {self.request!r}')
```

in views.py :

```
@shared_task
def run_file_to_process(self, id):
    do_something
```

P.S.: as mentioned above this code works properly on localhost but does not work when I build it on another environnment.

Comment: Is same version of celery running on your local & another environment?

Comment: yes, django-celery==3.3.1